# The data from the controller not showing up on the view JSP page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to show up the data retrieved from the database to the view using JSP, but they do not show up - even though they show up when print them out on the controller part. Can you please let me know what might the problem be? (Spring MVC used)

Here is the code for the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class CityController {

// need to inject the city dao
@Autowired
private CityDAO cityDAO;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String showHome() {

    return "home";
}

@GetMapping("/list")
public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {

    // get cities from the dao
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> GETING CITIES: ");

    List<City> theCities = cityDAO.getCities();

    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>> CITIES: " + theCities);

    for (City Cit : theCities) {
        System.out.println("City: " + Cit.getCityName());
    }

    // add the customers to the model
    theModel.addAttribute("cities", theCities);

    return "list-cities";
}
}
```

Here is the JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Cities</title>

<hr>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Cities </h2>

<hr>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>City Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- loop over and print our customers -->
            <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${cities}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${tempCustomer.cityName} </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>        
        </table>

 </body>

 </html>
```

The POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.evotingsystem</groupId>
<artifactId>mycoolwebapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>mycoolwebapp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>

<springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.45</mysql.connector.version>
    <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- C3PO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3po.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- to compensate for java 9 not including jaxb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


 </dependencies>
 <build>
 <finalName>mycoolwebapp</finalName>

 <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
 </build>
 </project>
```

Whereas the output I get is the following: 
-**${tempCustomer.cityName}**

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the `ArrayList` or any list on `JSP` in `Spring  MVC` framework, you can use the `JSTL`. [here more info](https://www.websparrow.org/spring/how-to-iterate-list-on-jsp-in-spring-mvc)

here your updated code :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Cities</title>

<hr>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Cities </h2>

<hr>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>City Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- loop over and print our customers -->
            <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${cities}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${tempCustomer.cityName} </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>        
        </table>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I added "<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>",  but still the same problem.

Comment: @Leo : have you added jstl dependency in the pom ?

Comment: Yes, I have added also the jstl dependency to the pom file, bit still same.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: do you have any other idea?

Comment: Add your pom.xml in question

Comment: I edited the question and added the pom.xml file. Please have a look once.

Comment: @Leo: I have build your project https://github.com/GovindParashar136/spring-mvc-java

Comment: @Leo checkout above git repository I have build your project and let me know is this resolve your problem

Comment: thanks a lot for your support. I have tried it, but it is still not working. I do not see where is the problem.

Comment: @Leo : Welcome,  did you check git hub repository  which is build with your code

Comment: @AvijitBarua : Why he need to use c:out ? He already using c:forEach because cities is a list

Comment: @GovindParashar I checekd your code on GitHub, but I was still having the problem. Then, I created another project from scratch, but this time I did create a maven project - and it was working.